# Scala Singleton Pattern: Private Primary Constructor

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a `singleton` using a private primary constructor and a companion object for that primary constructor's class.

Here is the code:

**Private Primary Constructor**

`class Car private(var model: String)`

**Companion Object**

```
object Car {
    val c = new Car("")
    def getInstance = c
}
```

So basically with the code above I will only have one instance of the `class Car` using the companion object. Something like this: `val car = Car.getInstance`?

Is this the correct way to do it? I am getting an error saying:

`error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be accessed in object Car`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying it in REPL? Repl doesn't handle companion objects, unless you use `:paste` mode. 
As long as class and object have the same name *and are in the same file* this should compile.

To answer your question though, no, this is not "the correct way to do it". The correct way would be to get rid of the class completely, and just use the object itself as the singleton.

Comment: Oh I see. I was reading a book and it said that this is a pattern. But by doing it just with an Object how would that work? Since I only want one instance of a class, I would need a separate class which I instantiate one time in the companion object. Can you please provide an example with only using object?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate anything. Just use the companion object _itself_: `object Car { val model = "BMW" }; println(Car.model)`

Comment: Yes but I want a single instance of a class. So I would need a separate class and inside of the companion object return an instance of that class which I would use over and over again. Since only using an `Object` is mainly just for factory methods. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `object` _is_ a single instance of (some) class. What specifically do you want that it does not do? No, it's not "mainly just for factory methods", it's for anything you would expect from a singleton.

Comment: Like a static class I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"? A singleton? Well ... that's `object` :)

Comment: The REPL does handle companion objects if you use paste mode.

Comment: Please do update the statement about REPL usage. Also, the common idiom is `trait Foo ; object Foo extends Foo`. That gives you a type besides `Foo.type` to code against.

Comment: Singleton class and object are not the same. With a singleton class you control the instantiation. That is, for example, if you need the dependency injection, objects are not the way to go. However, if you use DI, you should control singleton-ness of a class on the injection level, not via private static instances.

Comment: As for REPL and companion object, use Ammonite: http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL. It supports companion objects out of the box without any tricks like paste mode (it doesn't even have the paste mode, everything just works).

Comment: @Haspemulator the very idea is that you _do not want to control instantiation_. Just leave it to the jvm. This question has nothing to do with dependency injection.  You could "inject" objects if need be. It's a completely orthogonal discussion: we are talking about how to instantiate a singleton, not what to do with it after it was instantiated.

Comment: @som-snytt I did not not mention `extends Foo` thing on purpose to keep it focused on the question that was asked. The way OP phrased it, there is no need to be extending anything. I waited for him to explain "but I need the `Car` type to ...", but it looks like either he does not, or he figured out himself how to get it done.

Comment: @Dima I just wanted to put the question into a broader perspective. Singletons (as described in the Design Patterns book) are in and of themselves a dubious concept, being a mutable global state. There are better ways of getting the same behavior.